# Is there any way to recursive compile the source and generate `.deb` for the source and its all dependencies?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, package-management

My goal is to create an internal ubuntu repository server that hosts all the compiled (`.deb`) packages. I am planning to use this internal repo for install/updates instead of the official ubuntu server.

In order to achieve my goal, I need all the compiled packages (`.deb`). I am trying to generate `.deb` from a ubuntu package source like the one below.

```
apt-get source hostname=3.20
apt-get build-dep hostname=3.20 -y
cd hostname-3.20
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
```

Everything worked fine until this `.deb` creation. I have successfully created `.deb` for the `hostname` package from the source.

Now, I have done the following steps:

- Uploaded the `.deb` of `hostname` to the internal ubuntu server repository.
- Point the tools (say `debootstrap`) to this repository.

Now, If I tried to install `hostname`, `debootstrap` looks for the dependency of `hostname` which is `libgcc1`. I don't have `.deb` for `libgcc1` in the repository so, It threw the error saying `libgcc1` is not available.

Here is my question:

Is there any way to recursive compile the source and generate `.deb` for the source and all its dependencies?

Comment: I can't tell what but something went wrong: debhelper is a common dependency... for building sources, not for installing the binary result. it's supposed to be in a Build-Depends: control field (eg: https://tracker.debian.org/media/packages/h/hostname/control-3.21 ) and not appear anymore in the resulting binary.

Comment: That's true @A.B. I can see the dependencies on `Build-Depends` field of the control file under Debian. I can write a tool that reads that field recursively on every dependency until reaching the leaf (with no dependencies or has all dependencies available already). I'm thinking whether there is any tool available already to do this job. If there is any, I don't need to reinvent the wheel. Do you think I have to write a tool on my own?

Comment: @A.B I have replaced `debhelper` with `libgcc1`.

Comment: But why do you need to recompile these dependencies? Why not just mirror them?

Comment: My goal is to create a repository with very minimal packages and do that in an automated way. If I have a list of packages, my automation tool should be able to create a repository with those packages (including their dependencies).

Comment: So you dont need to recompile then. Just download some packages and their dependencies and adding them to a mirror should be enough.

Comment: I need to automate it, any idea how can I find the installation dependencies list for a particular package?